# Error while trying to open scene builder from eclipse, mac

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to open a .fxml file with scene builder from Eclipse on a Mac, but I get the error "Failed to launch SceneBuilder".

I have configured scene builder in preferences.

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your executable path is wrong.

Look in Window -> Preferences -> JavaFX

You should simply setup the path as "/Applications/SceneBuilder.app"